# Fade content in on load AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angularjs application which loads content from Instagram, however, on page load I would like to fade the loaded content in with a smooth transition.

I added `{{ loadedClass }}` to the main HTML tag but it doesn't seem to place ng-enter within it when it loads:

**HTML**

```
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <section ng-controller="ShowImages as images" class="page {{ loadedClass }}" ng-view>
```

**CSS**

```
.page.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
  animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
}

/* line 697, ../sass/app.scss */
.page.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 2s both ease-in;
  animation: fadeIn 2s both ease-in;
}
```

**Controller

```
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
                  $scope.loadedClass = 'page-feed';
          });**

 var app = angular.module('instafeed', ['ngAnimate']);
    app.filter('getFirstCommentFrom',function(){
  return function(arr, user){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      if(arr[i].from.username==user)
        return arr[i].text;
    }
    return '';
  }
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

http://machinas.com/wip/machinas/instagramfeed/

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Answer (score 0):

The directives that fire the enter event receive a class of `.ng-enter` when the DOM is updated. Angular then adds the `ng-enter-active` class, which triggers the animation. `ngAnimate` automatically detects the CSS code to determine when the animation is complete. When the event is done, Angular removes both classes from the DOM element, enabling us to define animatable properties to the DOM elements.

To actually run the animation, you need to include the CSS animation definition.

```
<script src="js/vendor/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Lastly you'll need to reference this library in your HTML after you reference Angular itself.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

---

```
.fade-in {
  -webkit-transition: 2s linear all;
  transition: 2s linear all;
}
.fade-in.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-in.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-in.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-in.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks, but it doesn't seem to be adding the ng-enter or ng-leave. with the code I have

Comment: Is `ngAnimate` included in your app?

Comment: Hi @Simo Endre When I add this   var app = angular.module('instafeed', ['ngAnimate']); it gives me an error

Comment: I see that $q provider isn't included. Can you may check if you include $q as dependency?

Comment: I'm checking the site. Now it does not give me that error with $q provider, but i see that the `fadeIn` style is not included in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css animations:

```
.fade-in {
  -webkit-transition: 2s linear all;
  transition: 2s linear all;
}
.fade-in.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-in.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-in.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-in.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

But in order for this to work you also have to include the `ngAnimate` module into your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

Also don't forget to include the actual script (this example uses Bower but there are others ways):

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Comment: when I add this   var app = angular.module('instafeed', ['ngAnimate']); it gives me an error.

Comment: Most likely because you haven't included it in your page. You have to download it then include it in your page, or use a CDN.

Comment: it is in my page, you can see here http://machinas.com/wip/machinas/instagramfeed/

Comment: try now sorry @Chrillewoodz

Comment: Hmm odd, can you try to move the var app outside your self invoking function? not that it should matter but ye